Was Ephesians 6:12 used historically to dehumanize opponents and justify physical war?
In Ephesians 6:12, Paul writes:
“For we do not wrestle against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the cosmic powers over this present darkness, against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly places.”
‭‭Ephesians‬ ‭6‬:‭12‬ ‭ESV‬‬
The standard, modern understanding of this passage is that our true opponents are not physical enemies, but rather evil spiritual forces that attempt to sow division and chaos.
How has this passage been used historically, and has it ever been used to justify war by dehumanizing the enemy? If so, could you point me to some examples?

One could spend a lot of time pondering and proving how the bible has been misused by other people. But I, personally, would rather spend my time properly understanding it unto my own edification. Welcome to SE-C. Please have a look at the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the 17,000 archived question/answer contributions as to how these principles play out in practice.

@NigelJ That is't really helpful. The question is how was it misused historically. I don't believe downvoting is appropriate here. Also, I respect your choice to place more value on the proper understanding of the passage, but I find your comment provides no helpful improvement to the question. Consider perhaps the OP is writing an essay and seeking an answer for a historical matter related to the passage. We don't know, so be kind and helpful instead.

@Wyrsa What you are describing is not an on-topic feature of this particular website. The site is called 'Christianity' and the purpose is to investigate, comparatively, the Christian religion. I have stated my own, personal preference and I believe I have that right. I cannot comment about voting as that is both a voluntary and a private matter.

Fair enough, strictly speaking this is "off-topic". Perhaps suggest the OP wants the catholic justification for like... the crusades? That would bring it back into topic and answer the original question the OP had. Win win, without any negativity.

history se might be a better place, purely based on asking for historical basis. Sure there is a bible verse but you seem to want to know if it has been used and when

I am not writing an essay or otherwise benefiting from the answer to this question. I simply was curious about whether it was used in the context of something similar to the Crusades. I would be happy to post this to another community if it isn’t appropriate for this one.
